# How do I add a class to a <tr> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm basically trying to turn one of the rows in a table to a different color. I'm currently using the jquery plugin Sheetrock to grab information from a google sheet. I want to turn the 9th row red when it's value is lower than 10.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I am working on right now: http://jsfiddle.net/m04ddeu2/435/ .

Here is the google sheet I'm grabbing info from:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlRp2ieP7izLdGFNOERTZW0xLVpROFc3X3FJQ2tSb2c#gid=0

HTML:

```
<table id="statistics" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
```

Javascript:

```
// Define spreadsheet URL.
var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlRp2ieP7izLdGFNOERTZW0xLVpROFc3X3FJQ2tSb2c#gid=0';

// Load an entire sheet.
$('#statistics').sheetrock({
    url: mySpreadsheet,
    rowHandler: formatRows
});

var formatRows = function (options) {

    var columnNumber = 9;
    var threshhold = 10;

    $('tr', options.target).each(function (i, el) {

        var $tableRow = $(el);
        var amount = $('td:nth-child(' + columnNumber + ')', $tableRow).text();

        if (parseInt(amount) <= threshhold) {
            $tableRow.addClass('warning');
        }

    });

};
```

CSS:

```
.warning {
color:red
}
```

I can't see any issues in my code. Is there something wrong with the way I'm writing my variables?

Comment: Have you verified that your row handler function (`formatRows`) is getting called? It doesn't appear to be in the jsfiddle.

Comment: first things first: check that your code is even firing with a `console.log("inside each for", el)` inside that `each` iteration, and check the dev tools console to see if that gets logged at all. Also log your `options` to see if `options.target` makes sense for what you're queryselecting in.

Comment: The documentation for Sheetrock's rowHandler https://github.com/chriszarate/sheetrock/blob/master/README.md#rowhandler suggests that it is looking for a function that will accept a row object and return a DOM object or string containing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The function that Sheetrock is looking for for rowHandler needs to be in the following form:

```
// Default row handler: Output a row object as an HTML table row.
var toHTML = function (row) {

    var cell;
    var html = '';

    // Use "td" for table body row, "th" for table header rows.
    var tag = (row.num) ? 'td' : 'th';

    // Loop through each cell in the row.
    for (cell in row.cells) {
        if (row.cells.hasOwnProperty(cell)) {
            // Wrap the cell value in the cell tag.
            html += wrapTag(row.cells[cell], tag, '');

            // you can add your logic here to test for ninth column value under 10

        }
    }

    // Wrap the cells in a table row tag.
    return wrapTag(html, 'tr', '');
};
```